# Ordering requirement for a combination of the redirection operators < and >

Tags: linux, shell

I found these two commands' outputs are same, when typing:

```
1. cat < file1 > file2
2. cat > file2 < file1
```

That's confused. Is there an order requirement when using these redirection operators?

Comment: The main thing which matters here is that orders of files are not changed with respect to redirection operators.i.e.,< must be preserved before file1 and > must be preserved before file2.The files occurence is not much of importance for cat command!

Comment: it's the same as how in C there is no difference between `a=5; b=4;` and `b=4; a=5;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [i/o stream redirection on linux shell. how does the shell process a command with redirection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215401/i-o-stream-redirection-on-linux-shell-how-does-the-shell-process-a-command-with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt McNabb points out, `< file1` and `> file2` are basically assignments interpretted before the command is run. They're pretty much interpretted as

```
input = "file1";
output = "file2";
execute cat
```

vs

```
output = "file2";
input = "file1";  
execute cat
```

which are obviously the same.

However, order does matter in some cases! Consider `cat > foo 2>&1`:

```
output = "foo";
error = output;
execute cat
```

In this case, error and output are the same. Compare to `cat 2>&1 > foo`:

```
error = output;
output = "foo";
execute cat
```

In this case, only `output` is set to `"foo"`, while `error` will refer to the default value for output (usually the terminal).

This means that the first version will write both output and errors to a file, while the second one will write just output to a file, and any errors to the terminal:

```
$ cat nosuchfile > foo 2>&1
(no output)

$ cat foo
cat: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
```

vs

```
$ cat nosuchfile 2>&1 > foo
cat: nosuchfile: No such file or directory

$ cat foo
(no output)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain these two instructions separately!

```
cat < file1 > file2
```

This instruction reads input from file1 and writes output to file2 and then cat displays it on the screen.

```
cat > file2 < file1
```

This instruction too does the same thing! This receives input from file1 and puts into file2 and then cat diplays it on the screen.

So,there is basically no difference.

**The order of the redirection does not matter. The only requirement is that the redirection operators (the "<" and ">") must appear after the other options and arguments in the command.**

Check this link for more help :- http://linuxcommand.org/lts0060.php

Answer (score 0):

@Jojo, in Linux, there is no ordering in file redirection.  The '<' and '>' tell the system whether the next filename is a gazinta or a gazouta (sink or source).  It doesn't matter the order.  The command line will use the last '> filenamexxx' for output and the last '< filenameyyy' for the input.

Try this:  ls >ttt1 >ttt2 /usr

Will you find the /usr directory listing in ttt1 or ttt2?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an order requirement when using these redirection operators?

For same type of stream yes. The shell indeed processes them in order but it doesn't matter when they are of different types.

These basically are the same with respect to behaviour.

```
cat < input > output ## Opens "input" for input (fd 0) and "output" for output (fd 1)
cat < outputt > input ## Opens "output" for output (fd 1) and "input" for input (fd 0)
```

But these would give different behaviours:

```
# Copies stream to stderr (2) from stdout (1) and open "output" as stdout (1).
# Here fd 1 and fd 2 are different. Stderr messages are sent to screen basically
# while stdout messages are sent to the file.
cat 2>&1 >output

# Redirections output to "output" and copies same stream to stderr.
# Here they are the same.
cat >output 2>&1
```